# Can I download the template from Joomla admin?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I need to modify a Joomla 1.5 template offline and can login to the backend as administrator. Can I download the template from there or do I need access to FTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to download the template package you should use `FTP`

For edit the template in Joomla you can user both `Joomla administrator and FTP`.

In Joomla administrator you can only edit `HTML(index.php) and CSS file`.

Go to,

```
Joomla administrator ---> Extensions ---> Template Manager ---> Select your template
```

In edit page you could see both options in top right side. Please refer this screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to access ftp to edit template files.If you want to download it from Admin back-end then you have to install `Akeeba backup` component to download it.

download link for akeeba backup: [Click Here](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/akeeba-backup.html)

Comment: No you don't, you can upload the template `zip file` without using FTP. akeeba backup is a recommended plugin, but it's not relevant to this question.

Comment: alfasin: I want to download, not upload template from my site.